# Проверка создалась ли папка в определенное время python

Tags: python-3.x

Хочу сделать оповещение в том случаи,  если не создалась папка.
У нас работает программа HandyBackup, которая в 23:00 создает папку с именем:

```
2016_07_27
```

Нужно раз в день к примеру в 9 часов утра проверять создалась ли эта папка или нет

```
import time
import datetime
import os 
from datetime import timedelta

yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
split = str(yesterday).split(' ')
replaceTire = split[0].replace("-" , "_") 
test = os.path.isdir('//host1/e$/BackUp/HandyBackUp/SQL1/' + replaceTire)

print(replaceTire)
print(test)
```

Я пока учусь программировать, но набросал такого вида скрипт, все отлично работает, но теперь не знаю как реализовать проверку по времени. Это должен быть вечный цикл и условие если. Хочу проверять наличие папки в 9 часов утра.
Важное дополнение надо к примеру,чтобы он один раз сообщил и забил на все, до следующей проверки, при бесконечном цикле он будет сообщать это постоянно !? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Таки по крону можно запускать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужен вам бесконечный цикл, с ним скрипт будет круглые сутки вхолостую крутиться - это полный изврат.

Сделайте скрипт, который будет срабатывать один раз в нужное время, и запускайте его по расписанию.

Поищите в гугле по запросу "планировщик заданий" с указанием вашей операционной системы.

Comment: cron на *nix или Windows Task Scheduler можно использовать, чтобы каждый день в 9 утра запускать указанный скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал такой вариант, насколько он правилен?

```
while True:
    now_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    split = str(yesterday).split(' ')
    replaceTire = split[0].replace("-" , "_")

    if (str(now_time) == "19:12:45"):
        test = os.path.isdir('//host1/e$/BackUp/HandyBackUp/SQL1/' + replaceTire)
        if(test==False):
            print("папки нет!")
            time.sleep(1)
```